# A question regarding standardized regression coefficient in a regression model with more than one independent variable

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

My question in full is: Why is the standardized regression coefficient in a regression model with more than one independent variable not the same as the correlation coefficient between x we interested in and y in a regression model with more than one independent variable?

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line) that $$ \hat {\beta_i} = {\rm cor}(Y_i, X_i) \cdot \frac{ {\rm SD}(Y_i) }{ {\rm SD}(X_i) } $$

So $$ {\rm cor}(Y_i, X_i) = \hat {\beta_i}  \cdot \frac{ {\rm SD}(X_i) }{ {\rm SD}(Y_i) } $$

The formula for the standardized regression coefficient is also:
 $$  standardizedBeta = \hat {\beta_i}  \cdot \frac{ {\rm SD}(X_i) }{ {\rm SD}(Y_i) } $$

So shouldn't it be 
$$  standardizedBeta =  {\rm cor}(Y_i, X_i) $$

?

Or is there something I missed?

Comment: Hi,  can you explain what is $SD$ and $standardizedBeta$?

Comment: SD is standard deviation. "standardizedBeta" is standardized regression coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\hat{\beta}_1 = r_{X,Y}\frac{s_X}{s_Y}, 
$$
is only holds for the simple model with an intercept term, i.e., for
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i.
$$
For multiple regression with $\{x_1,...,x_p\}$ the estimated coefficients are 
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y.
$$ 
Where the $k$th row of $X'X$ is 
$$
\left(\sum x_{ki}, \sum x_{ki}^2,..., \sum x_{ki}x_{ki}\right),
$$ 
and $X'y$ is of the following form 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum y_i \\
 \sum x_{1i}y_i \\
:\\
\sum x_{pi}y_i \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
hence I'm not sure that you can derive any insightful features from expressing explicitly the $\beta_k$ estimator in a multiple linear regression.

Comment: So is beta = cov(x,y)/var(x) also only apply for the case when there is only one independent variable in the regression model?

Comment: Yes, this is right